# QueryDict throws error when using split

Tags: python, django, curl

I have the following method in my `views.py`.

```
def update_module(request):
    rules =[]
    data = QueryDict(request)
    module_name = data.get('module_name')
    module_description = data.get('description')
    rule_ids = data.get('rule_ids')
    rule_names = data.get('rule_names')
    module_id = data.get('module_id')

    if rule_ids is not None:
        rule_ids = rule_ids.split(',')

    if rule_ids and rule_id[0]:
        rules = models.Rule.objects.filter(pk__in=rule_ids)

    elif rule_names:
        for rn in rule_names:
            rule = models.Rule(name=rn, user=get_current_user(request))
            rule.save()
            rules.append(rule)

    module = get_object_or_404(models.Module, pk=module_id)
    if module_name is not None:
        module.name = module_name
    if module_description is not None:
        module.description = module_description
    if rules is not None:
        for rule in rules:
            module.rules.add(rule)
    try:
        module.save()
    except Exception as e:
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'error': e.message}))

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(module.to_json()), content_type='application/json')
```

I am hitting it with a curl request as follows.

`curl -X PUT -data="module_name=rohit&description=sample&rule_ids=1,2,3&module_id=1" http://localhost:8000/module/`

It throws an exception saying.

```
Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/rokumar/SiteAnalysisGit/Src/hct/hct/views.py" in module_handler
  675.         return update_module(request)
File "/Users/rokumar/SiteAnalysisGit/Src/hct/hct/views.py" in update_module
  627.     data = QueryDict(request)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/http/request.py" in __init__
  328.                                         keep_blank_values=True):
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urlparse.py" in parse_qsl
  408.     pairs = [s2 for s1 in qs.split(&#39;&amp;&#39;) for s2 in s1.split(&#39;;&#39;)]

Exception Type: AttributeError at /module/
Exception Value: &#39;WSGIRequest&#39; object has no attribute &#39;split&#39;
```

Why is split not repent in a string.

Comment: consider that, somehow, the `qs` object is not a str in your error, but the WSGIRequest

Comment: Is that getting generated because of curl

Comment: no. see the line `data = QueryDict(request)` and change it to `data = QueryDict(request.body)` or `data = QueryDict(request._body)` (althought _body is protected - it is a bit hacky).